# can't find all occurrences of a string in a 2d array and then put each row in said 2d array into a 1d array

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, search

> A program is required to sort sentences from an input file. The sentences may contain the word ‘ERROR’, ‘INFORMATION’, or neither. Sentences with ‘ERROR’ go to an error log. Sentences with ‘INFORMATION’ go to an information log. Sentences that contain neither are not processed. The original input file should not be changed.
> The input file is named ‘Lorem_Ipsum.txt’.
> The information log is named ‘Info.log’ and already exists with a header in it.
> The error log is named ‘Error.log’ and does not exist.
> No internal data structure is needed for the solution.
> Make a backup copy of the existing files before writing the code for the required program.
> Note: In this example, there is no way to know when the last record has been written to a file, so do not worry about an extra line at the end of the output files.

This is the question i was asked to do for my computer science class.

```
#global variables
FILENAME = "Lorem_Ipsum (2).txt"
newFile = []
INFO = "INFORMATION"
ERROR = "ERROR"
info_log = []
error_log = []
#subprograms
def loadData():
    theFile = open(FILENAME, "r")
    for line in theFile:
        line = line.strip()
        theFields = line.split(".")
        aRecord = []
        aRecord.append(theFields[0])
        aRecord.append(theFields[1])
        newFile.append(aRecord)
    theFile.close()#up to here is correct. everything else is idk
def check(word, pList):
    if word in pList:
        print("The word is in the list!")
    else:
        print("The word is not in the list!")

            
#def writeData():
    #theFile.open(FILENAME, "w")
    #index = 0
    #newRecord = []
    #while index < len(newFile):
        #newRecord = newFile[index]
        #outLine = newRecord
    

#main program
loadData()
for theFields in newFile:
    print(theFields)
    check(INFO, theFields)
```

it prints out every sentence as not in the list, even though there are some which have the target word in the list. any help would be greatly appreciated.

For reference, I am doing the edexcel gcse computer science course.

Edit - Here are the first few lines of the Lorem_Ipsum (2).txt file:

Lorem INFORMATION ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.
Maecenas porttitor congue ERROR massa.
Fusce posuere, ERROR magna sed pulvinar ultricies, purus lectus malesuada libero.
Sit amet commodo magna eros quis urna.

As you can see, some have INFORMATION, some have ERROR and some have neither, and i need to separate them.

Comment: Where are you checking for the target words?

Comment: What's the `check()` function for? You never call it.

Comment: about that, when i call the check function, it doesn't work. i forgot to add it to the post. i must look like a right idiot

Comment: just added it now

Comment: i'm separating the sentences, not the words, if that makes sense. i need to look at each sentence and see if it has the target words in it. if so, move it to an output file.

Comment: I attempted that, but it printed out "word is not in the list" 14 times.

Comment: here's the code : def check(word, pList):
    for row in pList:
        if word in pList:
            print("The word is in the list!")
        else:
            print("The word is not in the list!")

Comment: for line in theFile:
        line = line.strip()
        theFields = line.split(".")
        newFile = []
        newFile += theFields

Comment: this doesn't return anything when the subprogram is called

Answer (score 0):

Let's start by fixing the loadData() function:

```
def loadData():
    sentences = []
    theFile = open(FILENAME, "r")
    for line in theFile:
        line = line.strip()
        theFields = line.split(".")
        sentences += theFields
    theFile.close()
    return sentences
```

Now on to the check() function:

```
def check(word, pList):
    for sentence in pList:
        if word in sentence:
            print("The word is in the sentence!")
        else:
            print("The word is not in the sentence!")
```

These 2 fixes should be enough to help you fix your code. I'll check back tomorrow to see if you need more help.

Comment: I renamed theFields sentences, it seems more correct; I define it AT THE START of the function, then RETURN it when it's filled. You should call the function with sentences = loadData(), then run the fixed check() function with check(word, sentences). You'll see it works far better.